# Wordpress: Inserting Posts from a JSON feed

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I have a file: **data.php** in my twentyfourteen theme directory which receives data from a JSON feed and then inputs it into the wordpress database.

The file is as follows:

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../wp-config.php");

$json_feed = "http://digitalrand.net/api/url_data/?key=********&pass=********%";
$json = file_get_contents($json_feed);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($obj as $article_array){
    $url = $article_array['url'];
    $title = $article_array['title'];
    $category = $article_array['category'];
    $large_summary = $article_array['summary'];
    $sum = implode(',',$large_summary);

    $post = array(
        'post_title' => [$title],
        'post_content' => [$sum],
        'post_status' => ['publish'],
        'post_type' => ['post'],
        'comment_status' => ['closed'],
        'post_template' => ['content.php']
        );

    wp_insert_post ($post, $wp_error);
}
?>
```

The above code throws an error: **Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\abacus\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 979**

I want the data to be input into the wordpress db as soon as it is received so that it can be included in the loop and displayed on the home page of my site.

Comment: Don't query a database inside a loop. Build a custom query inside that loop and execute it outside of the loop. Your DB admin will be grateful.

Comment: Why do you use brackets around the values ie `[` and `]`?

Comment: @AlexandruG. I don't know how to build a custom query inside a loop. Do you have pointers to any useful resources that could show me how to do it or if you don't mind please post an example of how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post = array(
        'post_title' => [$title],
        'post_content' => [$sum],
        'post_status' => ['publish'],
        'post_type' => ['post'],
        'comment_status' => ['closed'],
        'post_template' => ['content.php']
        );
```

Is not correct, it should be

```
$post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $sum,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_template' => 'content.php'
        );
```

Check here how its done

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: I just went through the post you shared. For example I have a category   of "business". How would I insert it into the database while associating it to the current article. I've seen the syntax is like this **'post_category' => [array(<category_id> ...)]** The problem is I have just a category name not an array

Comment: you can just do as `'post_category' => array({your value})`

Comment: I have that like this **post_category => array($category)** but I cannot see the record saved in the terms table which stores the categories. My articles stillvcome of as uncategorized on the view home page. By the way **$category** stores the category name only